# How to get all the properties of an object including the properties of every child object?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to get all the properties from an object including all the properties of it's child objects, for example:

You have a class A:

```
public class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; };
    public string Name { get; set; };
    public B BObject { get; set; };
}
```

And then the B class could look like this:

```
public class B
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; };
    public string BValue { get; set; };
}
```

How can I make sure when I use `PropertyInfo[] properties = a.GetType().GetProperties();` that I get all the properties for class A but also for class B toghether in the list?

Comment: Is only the next level needed or can this be nested Properties which are needed to be resolved recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine reflection with recursion to meet your needs：

```
 List<string> properties = new List<string>();
 GetAllProperties<A>(a,properties);
```

The method:

```
 public void GetAllProperties<T>(T type, List<string> properties)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the properties of 'Type' class object.
            PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo;
            myPropertyInfo = type.GetType().GetProperties();
            for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!myPropertyInfo[i].PropertyType.Namespace.Contains("System"))
                {
                    object newtype = Activator.CreateInstance(myPropertyInfo[i].PropertyType);
                    GetAllProperties<object>(newtype, properties);
                }
                else
                {
                    properties.Add(myPropertyInfo[i].Name);
                }

            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should add a try catch.

Comment: In case the Type hasn't got a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Furthermore, myPropertyInfo[i].PropertyType is already the needed Type, so Type.GetType is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding. I checked it according to your suggestion and I have modified the answer.

Comment: I'd only wrap try catch around the two lines: object newtype = Activator.CreateInstance(myPropertyInfo[i].PropertyType);
                    GetAllProperties<object>(newtype, properties); and wouldn't rethrow, so you get all Types, that work and the others will be ommited.

Comment: Thanks @YongqingYu for the answer! It is working but the only problem I have is that I have some ICollections in my class and when the method tries to create an instance of this ICollection is gives an error ```cannot create instance of an interface``` .

Comment: According to @bertilvandekerkhove requirements,  try to change the judgment to if(!myPropertyInfo[i].PropertyType.Namespace.Contains("System"))